# How to hide the border line of cells in NatTable

Tags: java, nattable, nebula

I wanto hide the boder line of cells in NatTable (Nebula). I tried with `Style` (set thickness = 0) but not yet successful :

```
Style textCellStyle = new Style();
textCellStyle.setAttributeValue(
                        CellStyleAttributes.BORDER_STYLE,
                        new BorderStyle(0, GUIHelper.COLOR_BLUE, LineStyleEnum.DASHED));
```

Can you give me some guide? Thank you very much!

**Update**: the code that I used:

```
NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, false);
ConfigRegistry configRegistry = new ConfigRegistry();
natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, 
                Boolean.FALSE);
///...
CompositeLayer composeLayer = new CompositeLayer(2, 2);
        composeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.CORNER, cornerLayer, 0, 0);
        composeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, columnHeaderLayer, 1, 0);
        composeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, rowHeaderLayer, 0, 1);
        composeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, viewportLayer, 1, 1);
natTable.setLayer(composeLayer);
natTable.refresh();
```

How can we apply the solution's Dirk in the BODY only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the grid lines and not border lines.

You can disable grid line rendering via

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, 
            Boolean.FALSE);
```

The following code just registers the setting for the body region:

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, 
            Boolean.FALSE,
            DisplayMode.NORMAL,
            GridRegion.BODY);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But this more than what I want: this also disable the grid line of the row header too. How can I apply to the body only?

Comment: The same way you do this with other configurations. Register it for GridRegion.BODY

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! This is my code: `viewportLayer.setRegionName("MyLabel");` `configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, Boolean.FALSE, DisplayMode.NORMAL, "MyLabel");`